# Problem getting WS channels from mainnet RPC

Tags: mainnet

Is anyone else experiencing problems with responses from mainnet RPC through websockets? Works fine for devnet, but for the last 6 hours+ it doesn't work on mainnet. What's going on? Solana status page shows all green for mainnet.

Comment: can you share specific error codes you receive from the websocket connection to the mainnet RPC, or otherwise explain what problems you are seeing? This will help us answer your question.